# Translate date(weekday, month) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Now when I add something to my database it enter created_at parameter also. When I use it in my view, it looks like this:

```
Thursday, 11 Jun 2015 9:52 AM
```

And I use it as:

```
<%= @current_feed.created_at.strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p") %>
```

Can I translate month and weekdays? Or create dictionary for it?

Comment: can you tell us what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .......

```
date = Date.parse('Thursday, 11 Jun 2015 9:52 AM')
 => Thu, 11 Jun 2015 
date.mon
 => 6 
date.mday
 => 11 
date.wday
 => 4
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Please refer this link http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking about date translation. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592235/rails-how-to-make-date-strftime-aware-of-the-default-locale).

You should use `I18n.localize`. Refer [this document](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).

You can also have a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787258/use-of-abbr-month-names-and-similars-with-i18n-l), to know how to have months in locale.